# split according to the whitespace with limited number substrings golang

Tags: go

I need to combine strings.SplitN and strings.SplitFunc. the input string might have any [kind of whitespace](https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/#IsSpace) and I just need the first two splitted substrings and remaining string should be parsed in another run. The SplitN function splits the input up to the N parameter but just consider space not whitespace. You can define your special splitter in SplitFunc, in my case something like this:

```
f := func(r rune) bool {
    return unicode.IsSpace(r)
}
```

but I can not define the number of substring in SplitFunc.

the function [strings.Fields](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Fields) is also not useful since there is no limit in this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

regexp Split appears to do what you require

```
s := regexp.MustCompile("[[:space:]]+")
r:=s.Split("the     final conflict.  Of Cheese", 3)
    fmt.Println("first two ",r[:2])
    fmt.Println("remaining ",r[2:])
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/-uoIljx0fKN

Answer (score 0):

You can use [strings.IndexFunc](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#IndexFunc) in a loop while trimming the string from left based on the found index.

A naive implementation could look like:

```
func findN(s string, limit int) []string {
    var found []string
    for i := 0; i < limit; i++ {
        nextIndex := strings.IndexFunc(s, unicode.IsSpace)
        if nextIndex < 0 {
            break
        }
        found = append(found, s[:nextIndex])
        s = s[nextIndex+1:]

    }
    return found
}
```

The whole code is here: https://play.golang.org/p/IZb8aV20ILW

Comment: it does not work properly. and also for a few space in a row, it may count every one while I want to count all of the spaces in a row as one space and skip them all. if you insert couple of spaces at the beginning or between substring it fails easily.

Comment: That's why I said "naive implementation" :)

Answer (score -2):

I wrote the answer in this way: first use string.Fields then grab as much as substring I want and remove them also from the source string

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    str := "      "

    substr, len := findN(str, 2)
    fmt.Printf("%q\n%d", substr, len)
}

func findN(str string, limit int) ([]string, int) {
    if len(str) <= 0 {
        return nil, 0
    }
    var substr []string
    for i := 0; i < limit; i++ {
        splitedS := strings.Fields(str)
        if len(splitedS) < 1 {
            break
        }
        v := splitedS[0]
        substr = append(substr, v)
        str = strings.TrimSpace(str)
        str = strings.TrimPrefix(str, v)
        str = strings.TrimSpace(str)
    }
    str = strings.TrimSpace(str)
    if str != "" {
        substr = append(substr, str)
    }
    return substr, len(substr)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/kQnbYbP_hXf

Comment: This would panic if the string has less than 2 substrings

Comment: I edited it. I believe it works pretty fine. thanks for notice.

Comment: @Karimai: It's inefficient because you repeatedly apply `strings.Fields(str)`.